# Hacer que una sesión se mantenga activa Flutter

Tags: mysql, android, ios, flutter, dart

Buenas tengo una app donde he creado una ventana para que mis usuarios inicien sesión, los datos los estoy recogiendo desde MySQL por medio del plugin MySQL1.

Recibo bien los datos y me entra en la app bien, el problema es que quiero que se mantenga la sesión activa, es decir, no quiero que cada vez que ejecute la app me pida que inicie sesión denuevo, no se como hacerlo, es mi primera app con sesiones de usuario.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es que cada vez que logras ingresar correctamente, el servido debe retornar un token como respuesta, además de los datos de usuario.

Guarda los datos de usuario para mostrar (no contraseña ni login) y el token, te recomiendo que uses el plugin de [`shared_preferences`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) .

Luego cuando entres a la app validas si ya tienes guardado el token , si es así ingresas directamente a la app, también podrías enviar un request sin intrusión con el token como parámetro, para que en tu servidor puedas validar si ya expiró o no y puedas sacar al usuario de sesión.

Agrega el plugin en el archivo `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.2
```

Importalo

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

El uso es sencillo

```
        _saveValue(String token) async {
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          await prefs.setString('token', token);
        }

        Future<String> _returnValue() async {
            SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            final token = await prefs.getString("token");
            return token;
        }
```